# Problem with setting static IP on Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: networking, 14.04, static-ip

I have a problem setting the static IP on my Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS.

When I:

1. run `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`, then
2. change **dhcp** to **static**, then
3. I type `address,netmask,network,gateway,dns-nameservers`, then
4. I try to ping a reliable website (e.g. `yahoo.com`)

I get an error in response like `unknown host yahoo.com` and sometimes `destination unreachable`.

I also tried to connect through PuTTY, but that's only a local IP. What I actually need is a real IP (like this 109.92.21.200), so that I can connect through PuTTY (which I have on my laptop) and connect to port 22 on my desktop server which is open, but I am constantly getting an error like "Connection timed out" or "Connection refused".

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Can you post the content of the /etc/network/interfaces file ? Also can you try to ping 8.8.8.8 and post output ?

Comment: ok, so the output od /etc/network/interfaces file is             address 192.168.1.12                                             netmask 255.255.255.0                                              gateway 192.168.1.1                                                  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4                                  so than i do sudo service networking restart and i get message    stop:Job failed while stoping                                 start:Job is already running : networking

Comment: ok if you ping 192.168.1.1 or ping 8.8.8.8 from your machine do you get any reply ?

Comment: i get the following -> connect: Network is unreachable

Comment: I need more information so I can help. Is 192.168.1.1 a router device in your LAN that connects you to the Internet? What type of connection do you have PPPoE, DSL, direct ? If you machine physical or virtual ?

Comment: i setup server on virtual machine .... 192.168.1.1 is the address of router...just give me your e-mail and we can disscuss futher more and i can give you access to my local so you can help me configure that...Is that ok?

Comment: I do not know if it's ok to post an email address here.

Comment: can i write on your blog site and ask you question and post my e-mail so we can communicate?

Comment: If you are using a VM in VirtualBox for example go to Settings -> Network and make sure in the Attached to box you have selected Bridged adapter and the name of the interface is correct (e.g. eth0) as the one you use for your main PC to get to the Internet

Comment: yes you can write to me

Comment: i send a e-mail to you on your blog site...please check and inform me ...

Comment: @user283469 Having the same trouble. Can you post more about how this situation turned out?

Answer (score 3):

When I needed to set a static IP address for my ubuntu pc, I did it from the router rather than trying to set it from the pc.

The router then sets the IP address given in the router table for the device on each power up.

Comment: Your router assigns dynamic IP thru DHCP, but a question is about static IP

Comment: @dyomas That is exactly so but it is usually possible to reserve a static IP address for a specifically identified device in the DHCP table which correctly answers the op's question.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give an instance of what you actually have in your interfaces file to make it easy for us to see where you're going wrong.  But if you're going to use a manual configuration you'll have to specify other important components which would normally be provided by your dhcp server.

This is an example of a working /etc/network/interfaces configuration:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.123
  gateway 192.168.1.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  dns-search apollo3.com # ths is the doman sufix that you want added to a one word hostname
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

There are other configurations that you can set.  However, these are the most needed that are provided by your dhcp server

You can probably get these items by running ifconfig when using the dhcp server, or from your isp/network provider

Comment: do i need to do service networking restart command or can i try     /etc/init.d/networking restart ? I set my static ip like you described but with other parameters...

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you are going through the right process. but go through some settings more to make your network interface working.

Setting up Ip address in /etc/network/interfaces restart your network interface services.

If you are getting the same problem then

Open terminal and **run mii-tool** it will show your network card duplex mode. change your duplex mode to 100baseTx-FD to 10Mbit by running this command in terminal.

**sudo mii-tool -F 10baseT-HD**

should be fixed you problem.

Comment: ok .. so when i do service networking restart i got this            stop:Job failed while stoping                                          start:Job is already running : networking                              Am i doing the right thing?

Comment: Reboot your system and remove all entry from **/etc/network/interfaces** and Set manual ip address from terminal. `sudo ifconfig eth0 10.0.0.100 netmask 255.255.255.0` `sudo route add default gw 10.0.0.1 eth0` `sudo vim /etc/resolve.conf` `nameserver 8.8.8.8` `nameserver 8.8.4.4` try it.

Comment: i have done like you told me and now i get error trying to ping 192.168.1.1 -> connect : Network is unreachable.

Comment: Now go through this [link]https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html this is the official site of Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Force the interface down and up works.

```
  sudo ip link set eth0 down
  sudo ip link set eth0 up
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ls /sys/class/net
```

the above steps and most of the recommendations online will work if you first 
determine the right `nic` name for your Ethernet port with the above command

I was using eth0 as recommended above but looking at the directory `/sys/class/net`
told me the name of my adapter device was em0 instead of `eth0`
once I put the `em0` instead of `eth0` in the above `/etc/network/interfaces` file
I had no slow boot and I could ping out.

Answer (score -2):

You do not need to change /etc/network/interfaces or any part of your config beyond your dns servers!

The issue is different flags being set for dnsmasq for static ips vs dynamic ip addresses. For static ip address, dnsmasq sets --proxy-dnssec by default. Most IPS do not provide dnssec capable dns servers and therefore dnsmaq timesout. If you set the ip addresses for the dns servers in network manager to a publicly offered dns server with dnssec (google is a good one: 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4) everything goes back to working.  You do not need to override resolve in any other way.